# Extrinsic Curvature in Schwarzchild Space

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

I am reading [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0301012) on extrinsic curvature embedding diagrams in general relativity: it seems that these are used to visualize curved space.  On page 2, it is stated that in the case of the constant Schwarzschild time hypersurface in a Schwarzschild spacetime, the extrinsic curvature embedding is a flat surface.  Does that mean that if you take the $t=0$ hypersurface in Schwarzchild spacetime (ie. the spatial part of the Schwarzchild metric) given by

$g_{SC}= \Bigg(1 + \frac{m_0}{2 r} \Bigg) \delta$

that the extrinsic curvature $k_{ij}$ of this hypersurface is just the flat metric $\delta_{ij}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it means that the extrinsic curvature is zero. Don't confuse the curvature with the metric! The metric of the hypersurface is in this case conformal to a flat metric, but that's not what we're saying. The extrinsic curvature is zero because the 4D metric is static, not because of any particular form of the 3D metric.

Comment: I see, so even if take the 3D metric to be a small perturbation of the $t=0$ slice of the Schwarzchild spacetime, the extrinsic curvature will still vanish due the 4D metric?

Comment: @Tom What do you mean by a small perturbation? The extrinsic curvature depends on how the hypersurface is embedded in the ambient spacetime; if you change it so that it isn't a $t = \text{const}$ surface anymore, the extrinsic curvature won't be zero.

Comment: I guess what I am really asking is: take a 4D manifold where the metric is given by a small perturbation of the Schwarzchild metric ie. add some metric $h_{\alpha \beta}$ with components whose size is small in a suitable norm (in general I suppose this metric will neither be spherically symmettric or static).  Now if we take a spacelike hypersurface of this 4D manifold, what would the induced metric and the extrinsic curvature be? I assume the extrinsic curvature is no longer going to vanish in this case

Comment: @Tom yes, in general there would be no reason for the extrinsic curvature to vanish. That and the induced metric depend on the perturbation and on the way you choose the hypersurface, for which you have pretty much complete freedom.

Comment: Could one just choose the hypersurface at $t=0$, as one wants an initial data anyway.  In this case, what would the induced metric and the extrinsic curvature be for the hypersurface (or at least what would the general form be assuming any perturbation $h_{\alpha \beta}$?

Comment: @Tom To be honest I don't know, that sounds like the kind of thing you should look for in a book. Poisson's *A Relativist's Toolkit* has a bunch of stuff on hypersurfaces, you might have some luck there.

Comment: Yes this is a bit confusing as I am not sure what the $t=0$ hypersurface would be as the perturbation could be time-dependent (object thrown into the black hole, for example).  It seems to me that people prove that something is true for a spherically symmetric spacetime by proving it for spherically symmetric initial data sets (ie. hypersurfaces).  Can one prove something is true for a perturbation of Schwarzchild spacetime by proving it for a perturbation about a hypersurface in standard Schwarzchild spacetime?  But then surely one still needs to know the extrinsic curvature from somewhere...

Comment: ie. the spacelike Schwarzchild metric where $t=0$ is a spacelike slice of the 4D Schwarzchild metric, so if we add a perturbation to the spacelike Schwarzchild metric is that also a spacelike slice of a perturbation of the 4D Scwharzchild metric?

Comment: @Tom I think there is some deeper purpose behind your questions which is not coming across clearly. What motivates your questions? But anyway, it's hard to make any general statements about an arbitrary surface. You might be interested in the concept of a Cauchy surface, which is one from which you can predict all the future of your spacetime.

Comment: The motivation is tthat I am seeing if I a method I have works to prove the Penrose inequality for black hole spacetimes which are perturbations of Schwarzchild spacetime.   However, I am getting slightly confused as the inequality is stated in terms of initial data formulation for 3-manifolds which are hypersurfaces of the spacetime and in that formulation one needs the induced metric and the extrinsic curvature of the hypersurface, so basically what is the 3-manifold in that case.  For spherically symmetric spacetimes, I think one proves it for a spherically symmetric Cauchy data.

Comment: In my case, I am not sure what the initial data would need to be to prove the result for a perturbation of a Schwarzchild spacetime, or what the general form would be for the induced metric and extrinsic curvature.